# Add plugin to minecraft server

Tags: plugins, server, minecraft

I downloaded the minecraft java server .jar file and it works well.
But now i want to add java plugins into the server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends in the type of the minecraft server.

For spigot server here: https://www.spigotmc.org/.

For bukkit server here: https://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins.ect

But **if you are using vanilla minecraft server YOU CAN'T use any type of plugins**, at least with any official way.

I hope i helped you.

Comment: Thanks, I will use Spigot